# Customizing wp_link_pages

Tags: wp-link-pages

I want to create a pagenation using wp_link_pages that looks like this

**Previous**   3 of 20   **Next**

How can this be achieved?

I am using this function btw https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this with just the standard arguments but you can do it with a filter:

```
function link_hack_wpse_($output,$args) {
  global $page, $numpages;
  $xofy = $page.' of '.$numpages;
  if (1 == $page) {
    $output = str_replace($args['after']," $xofy{$args['after']}",$output);
  } elseif ($page == $numpages) {
    $output = str_replace($args['before'],"{$args['before']}$xofy ",$output);
  } else {
    $output = str_replace('</a><a',"</a> $xofy <a",$output);
  }
  return $output;
}
add_filter('wp_link_pages','link_hack_wpse_',10,2);

$args = array(
  'before'           => '<p>',
  'after'            => '</p>',
  'next_or_number'   => 'next',
  'separator'        => '',
  'nextpagelink'     => __( 'Next' ),
  'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous' ),
  'pagelink'         => '%',
  'echo'             => 1
);defaults

wp_link_pages( $args );
```

I should note that this is very dependent upon the `$args` settings. It is not going to be portable without modification.

Comment: Thanks! I was just starting to look towards this direction. This work's and does just what I need. I also had some code to replace the wp_link_pages with my own custom function which also worked nicely. Thanks for the code!